# Do dragons marry human women?

Tags: dragons, european-folklore, medieval-europe, love

I found a collection of 3 love stories from medieval European folklore about dragons disguising themselves as handsome men to seduce beautiful women, usually a princess and marry them.

Is this a common motif in folklore (European) about dragons?

https://exemplore.com/legends/Shape-Shifting-Dragons-of-Folklore

Comment: Where in Europe?  Eastern European dragons tend to be more human-like (such as human sized) than Western ones.

Comment: If you read the article the stories all take place in France (Aquitaine, Poitou, and Gascony.